# error from dialog when using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I get a an alert: Object XMLHttpRequest. This happens when I click Add Recipient on my dialog. The code below POSts the new values to the database. It opens a dialog or form and the action of the form is to add or insert a new value to the database. I pasted the code below because I think thats likely the source of the error. 
Below is the javascript for my code:

```
 $(function () {
              $('#dialog-form-add').dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  modal: true,
                  height: 425,
                  width: 475,
                  buttons: {
                      'Add Recipient': function () {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: $("#add-recipient-form").attr('action'),
                              data: $("#add-recipient-form").serialize(),
                              dataType: "text/plain",
                              success: function (response) {
                                  $('#dialog-form-add').dialog('close');
                                  $("#grid").load('/Default/ #grid', function () {
                                      $('tbody > tr:first')
                                  .effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
                                  });
                              },
                              error: function (response) {
                                  alert(response);
                                  $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
                              }
                          });
                      },
                      Cancel: function () {
                          $('#dialog-form-add').dialog('close');
                      }
                  }
              });
              $('#requestdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

              $('#add-recipient')
              .button().click(function () {
                  $('#dialog-form-add').dialog('open');
              });

          });
```

Comment: Try inspecting your AJAX call in FireBug and see what status code does the server return. Also what happened when you placed a breakpoint in your action? Was it hit? Did the action execute successfully?

Comment: @darin-dimitrov Thanks. I removed dataType: "text/plain", and it worked after using the firebug. Had little experience and had to apply your suggestion. Thanks.